# Mocking a class with multiple mocked dependency as constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I've been trying to mock my service/business class to start testing my app but there are many "dependencies" on other class, mainly Repositories and a stub passed to those repository.
I've been trying to set this up in order to be able to unit test my service but i keep on getting errors and i don't really know if my setup is right or not :

I haven't included the Interfaces as i felt there weren't necessary but could if needed.

```
    public abstract class  DemoRepo<T> implements Repository<T> {

        private dbStub stub;
        private Class<T> clazz;


        public DemoRepo(DbStub stub,Class<T> clazz){
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.stub = stub;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(T item) {
            stub.inSert(item);
        }
        @Override
        public void update(T item) {
            stub.update(item);
        }
        ...

    }
```

Then those 2 repository extends the abstract class for each class

```
    public class Class1Repo extends DemoRepo<Class1> {
        public Class1Repo(DbStub stub) {
            super(stub,Class1.class);
        }
    }


    public class Class2Repo extends DemoRepo<Class2> {
        public Class2Repo(DbStub stub) {
            super(stub,Class2.class);
        }
    }
```

Then same for the abstract service which use the 2 repositories created before.

```
    public abstract class AbstractService implements ClassService {
        private Repository<Class1> class1Repository;
        private Repository<Class2> class2Repository;

        public AbstractService(Repository<Class1> class1Repository, Repository<Class2> class2Repository) {
            this.class1Repository = class1Repository;
            this.class2Repository = class2Repository;
        }

        public boolean itemValiation(String itemId){
            Class1 item = class1Repository.findOne(itemId);
            item.setValidated(true);
            class1Repository.update(item);
            return true;
        }

        .....

    }
```

Finally this the service what i'm trying to test :

```
    public class DemoImplService extends AbstractService {

        public DemoImplService(Class1Repo c1repo,Class2Repo c2repo){
            super(c1repo, c2repo);
        }
    }
```

But as you can see i'm gonna need to pass 2 mocked repositories which themself are instantiated from a mocked " stub" and that's my issue.

I've tried to do it many different ways but here is the most recent one giving me trouble :

```
class DemoImplServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private DbStub stub;

    private DemoImplService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private Class1Repo repo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Class2Repo repor;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
        Class1Repo repo = new Class1Repo(stub);
        Class2Repo repor = new Class2Repo(stub);
        DemoImplService service = new DemoImplService(repo,repor);
    }

    @Test
    void itemValiation() {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        **when (repo.findOne("1")).thenReturn(c1);**
        //java.lang.NullPointerException
    }

}
```

My logic here was to try to use the mock / injectmocks mechanism and then just mocking the repository as i don't really need to mock the Stub but it's not compiling i'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I've also tried setting up the 2 repository with       `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` but i'm not even compiling this way so i gave up.

---

Update :

new class

```
class DemoImplServiceTest {

@Mock
private Class1Repo repo;
@Mock
private Class2Repo repor;
@InjectMocks
private DemoImplService service;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    Class1 object = new Class1();
    when (repo.findOne("1")).thenReturn(object);
}

@Test
void itemValiation() {
   boolean updated = service.itemValiation("1");
   assertTrue( updated );
   verify( repo ).findOne("1");
   ArgumentCaptor<Class1> class1Captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass( Class1.class );
   verify( repo ).update( class1Captor.capture() );
   Class1 updatedCclass1 = class1Captor.getValue();
   assertTrue( Class1.isValidated() );
}
```

This line `boolean updated = service.itemValiation("1");` is what's failling : java.lang.NullPointerException

I've tried declaring

```
    Class1 object = new Class1();
    when (repo.findOne("1")).thenReturn(object);
```

inside the `void itemValiation()` func but that didn't change anything

Last thing is that if i add the method `service = new DemoImplService(repo,repor);` inside the test function i'm getting a different null pointer exception this time located in the AbstractService inside the itemValidation method for that line `class1Repository.update(item);`

Update 2

The full exception without instantiating the class :

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jd.mypackage.test.services.ImplServiceTest.itemValiation(ImplServiceTest.java:187)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(MethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$141/655381473.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:81)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$109/981661423.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$109/981661423.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$109/981661423.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: There is no need to create object if you use injectMocks.Please paste the line no where you are getting null pointer exception

Comment: when (repo.findOne("1")).thenReturn(c1);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use @InjectMocks on the class you want to test and @Mock on the dependencies of that class.

```
class DemoImplServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private DemoImplService service;

    @Mock
    private Class1Repo repo;

    @Mock
    private Class2Repo repor;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but what about the mock of the DbStub to instantiate the class1 repo ? isn't it necessary ?
    `@Mock
    private DbStub stub;

    @InjectMocks
    private Class1Repo repo;

    @InjectMocks
    private Class2Repo repor;    private 

=>  @InjectInjectedMocks
    DemoImplService service;`

Comment: You don't need that since you are creating mocks and they just simulate the behavior of the real objects.

Comment: Are you still getting the exception? Just asking because you accepted the answer after your last comment

Comment: Actually i'm still getting the exception it has just moved.  now when(repo.findOne("1")).thenReturn(c1); works. But `DemoImplService. itemValiation()` doesn't :(....

Comment: can you show what your itemValiation test method looks like now? Or you can update the whole test class so i can see what you actually changed.

Comment: If you are using @InjectMocks you don't have to instantiate your service class manually the annotation will do it for you. Is the service object null  or the null pointer comes from the original itemValiation method?

Comment: Hmm it is strange, it seems the service object is null already.
you should debug the test and watch where the nullpointer comes from. If the servie object is null something is wrong with the initialization then try to remove InjectMocks annotation and create it manually in the seutup method after initMocks.

Comment: im getting null for all 3 objects in the debugger..service , repo, repor

Comment: Hmm I've run out of ideas, annotations should work.
One more thing you can try is to set up everything manually for example
repo = Mockito.mock(Class1Repo.class);
repor = Mockito.mock(Class2Repo.class);
service = new DemoImplService(repo,repor);

Comment: I think it's an issue with the @Before. `repo = Mockito.mock(Class1Repo.class); repor = Mockito.mock(Class2Repo.class); service = new DemoImplService(repo,repor);`  when inserting this into the body of each of my methods it works fine....

Comment: I am not sure about mokito but in jmockit you cannot verify and expect on the same method... could this be an issue?